# Are there caveats of using mutable types as default parameters in functions in Python?

Tags: python, function, mutable, default-parameters

I have recently read about mutable default parameters in Python.
For some reason, I came up with an idea of using it like this:

```
data = [3, 4, 1, 8, 5, 9, 2, 6, 7]


def get_min(checked=[]):
    global data

    mn = min((x for x in data if x not in checked))
    checked.append(mn)

    return mn
```

The code is pretty useless, and it can easily be replaced by a generator, but I am wondering if I should ever use such a technique in my projects. Are there any hidden caveats of doing such a thing?

I have read some similar questions, but all I see are constant arguments about how this thing is a design flaw. So I want to get a clear answer: should I use it, or shouldn't I, and why?

Comment: [Famously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument), yes.

Comment: Much better to use `(checked=None)` and something like `if not checked:` / `checked = []`.

Comment: And, BTW, you don't need the `global` statement unless you are assigning a new value to `data`.

Comment: @TimRoberts That wouldn't be persistent, though.

Comment: Ah, now I see.  He was actually trying to EXPLOIT this hole.  Bad assumption on my part.

Comment: @TimRoberts exploit seems like an evil word to describe that :D But yeah, I wonder if you can make a good use of this thing

Comment: Well, maybe not "evil", but I guarantee it's going to confuse the next person who has to maintain your code.

Comment: @TimRoberts If nobody else is able to maintain your code, you can't get fired. 

Comment: @KellyBundy boss move right there :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main caveat is that someone reading your code later, unless they're familiar with this particular gotcha, might not understand that `checked` persists, or that the caller isn't actually intended to ever provide a value for it.  Assuming you wanted to avoid generators, it would be more clear to write something like:

```
data = [3, 4, 1, 8, 5, 9, 2, 6, 7]
checked = []

def get_min():
    mn = min(x for x in data if x not in checked)
    checked.append(mn)
    return mn
```

Comment: So there are no technical secrets behind this thing, that can possibly break it? Only the matter of knowledge?

Comment: There generally aren't "secrets" in programming.  Things work the way they work.  With a few specific exceptions, nobody intentionally designs a language with hidden random pitfalls.  :)

Comment: In other words @aleksandr-novik, in a sense, yes, but in a more important sense, "technical secret" and "matter of knowledge" are *the same thing*. They feel different when the piece of knowledge you were missing is unexpected, surprising, or from a lower level of abstraction, and caused some code to behave in a way you didn't expect. Technical secrets are the result of designing things while feeling that these kinds of "matter of knowledge" effects are okay.